# IE ignores hosts file; works in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, hosts-file

I've edited my hosts file in a Windows 7 VM, but it doesn't work in IE. It works with Firefox, though. I hope this itemized list will help more than a verbose description.

### Environment

- Windows 7 in a VirtualBox VM, Linux (ArchLinux) host
- VM has a bridged network adapter
- The hosts file has a series of entries to the same IP for different hosts names:

  ```
  192.168.1.100    one.local
  192.168.1.100    two.local
  ```
- The Internet options has no proxy configured and no automatic configuration.

### What I've done

- Restarted IE
- Restarted Windows
- Ran *ipconfig /flushdns*
- *ping one.local* returns 192.168.1.100

### Results

- Firefox works; requests to one.local return the webpage from my Windows VM's host.
- IE returns Bing search results for one.local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you change the domain to one.local.com?

`local.` is not an available TLD, so IE might be auto-redirecting anything that can't be a valid URL on the internet to whatever search provider you have configured.

Comment: Thank you, Darth Android. It worked. Do you know off hand if I can change that behavior with a configuration change?

Comment: I was looking through that now; The company I'm at uses *.local for their internal websites, but that's configured by the DNS server and not via the `hosts` file. You might try turning off search suggestions from the providers in `Tools` -> `Internet Options` -> `General` tab -> `Search` section -> `Settings` -> `Search Providers` tab -> disable suggestions for each provider.

Answer (score 1):

actually you just need to put http:// in front of it,  Firefox tries this automatically for everything before going to search,  IE will only do it with known TLDs. (like .com)

Comment: Can you expand upon this? It's not obvious how this addresses the question.